# What template parameter do I use? (C++ conceptual question)

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, constructor

I am going through the book C++ Crash Course by Josh Lospinoso and have been compiling the code in the lessons along the way. I'm having trouble with the following code (which is a simplified version of one of the examples in the book).

```
struct SmallStruct {};

template <typename T>
struct BigStruct {
    BigStruct(const T& arg) : arg{arg} {};
private:
    const T& arg;
};

int main() {
    BigStruct main_struct{[](const SmallStruct&) {}};
}
```

The main part of this code I don't understand is the statement in `main()`, specifically constructing with a lambda function. I know the code doesn't compile because when instantiating the `BigStruct` object in `main()` it is lacking a template parameter. I've tried `<SmallStruct>`, `<SmallStruct&>` as parameters but neither compile. If anyone could explain what is going on it would be really beneficial for my learning.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If this does not compile for you, your compiler is likely set to a too old version of the language standard. Compiles just fine for me with `g++ -std=c++17`. The template parameter is whatever the type of the constructor argument happens to be.

Comment: You need [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to make that compile. It was introduced in c++17.

Comment: Thanks that worked. So then why do we not need to provide a template parameter when instantiating a BigStruct object? Is it automatically deduced?

Comment: Thanks @super just saw your link. Very helpful

Comment: @Lachlan The constructor arguments need to allow to deduce the template types from, which is the case in your example. A default constructor, for instance, wouldn't allow to do so, in such a case you'd still have to specify the template arguments...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat `+[](const SmallStruct&) {}` will return a `void(*)(const Smallstruct&)`, the lambda expression has an un-utterable type

Comment: @Caleth Yes, correct. I forgot for a moment that every lambda coins its own unique type... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "old" days the way was to use a `make_...` helper function to get the template parameter deduced from a function parameter:

```
struct SmallStruct {};

template <typename T>
struct BigStruct {
    BigStruct(const T& arg) : arg{arg} {};
private:
    const T& arg;
};

template <typename T>
BigStruct<T> make_big_struct(const T& t){
    return {t};
}

int main() {
   auto main_struct = make_big_struct([](const SmallStruct&) {});
}
```

Since C++17 there is [CTAD (class template argument deduction)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) and your code compiles without error as is because `T` can be deduced from the parameter to the constructor (https://godbolt.org/z/oWrnc6bah).

Comment: Yet another variant for the old days: `auto lambda = ...; BigStruct<decltype(lambda)>bs(lambda);` – especially useful if the struct is just a small, specifically designed helper class within a function...

Comment: Notice that the "old" `make_XXX` is still useful (at least in generic code) when copy-constructor would be used for CTAD (`std::optional(other_optionnal);` return a copy, whereas `std::make_optional(other_optionnal);` would give an `std::optional<std::optional<U>>`).